# Monitoring Nodejs clusters after restart

Tags: node.js

I am creating a monitor service for my Nodejs server that monitors the four clusters. The monitor should provide statistics based on each individual cluster, including columns like files sent, files received, etc.

Each cluster is represented by a PID, but when we restart the Nodejs server, the PID gets reset. Is there a way to monitor the 4 clusters and link the old PIDs to the ones? That way, I can truly monitor each cluster instead of monitoring statistics based on PID.

Comment: I understand this might not be what you're looking for, but have you tried [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)?  It's a popular service for monitoring node processes, and supports clustering.

Comment: @dylants Yeah I am currently using PM2, however, it doesn't track all the incoming and outgoing file transfers. That is the key statistic I need right now.

Comment: I have another use case but I want exactly the same. Is there a solution do identify my cluster, even if it was respawned ```cluster.fork()``` again?